# How to plus one at the tail to a float number in Python?

Tags: python

Is there a simple and direct way to add 'one' at float number in Python?

I mean this:

```
if a == 0.0143:
    a = plus(a)
    assert a == 0.0144

def plus(a):
    sa = str(a)
    index = sa.find('.')
    if index<0:
        return a+1
    else:
        sb = '0'*len(sa)
        sb[index] = '.'
        sb[-1] = 1
        return a+float(sb)
```

This is not what I want, because it gives me 0.0144000000001.

Comment: This is an awesome question. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As you've noticed, not all decimal numbers can be represented exactly as floats:

```
>>> Decimal(0.1)
Decimal('0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625')
>>> Decimal(0.2)
Decimal('0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125')
>>> Decimal(0.3)
Decimal('0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875')
>>> Decimal(0.4)
Decimal('0.40000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625')
>>> Decimal(0.5)
Decimal('0.5')
```

Since you're working with the properties of decimal numbers, use the `decimal` module, which implements them exactly:

```
from decimal import Decimal

def plus(n):
    return n + Decimal('10') ** n.as_tuple().exponent
```

And a demo:

```
>>> n = Decimal('0.1239')
>>> plus(n)
Decimal('0.1240')
```

You have to represent the number as a string, as representing it as a float will lose precision.

The downside is that using `Decimal` will make your `plus` function about 20-30 times slower than if you used floating point operations, but that's the cost of precision.

Comment: +1 for actually being readable. Doing this kind of stuff is so easy to make a mess of code with.

Comment: Note that as of Python 3.3, the `decimal` module is implemented in C, and should not be that much slower than using floats.

Comment: floats are impemented in the CPU and should be faster.

Comment: @Matthias: But not 20-30 times faster (compared to Python 3.3 decimals).

Answer (score 2):

Blender's answer is definitely a good answer, but if you insist to use `floats` I believe the simple way to do this is:

1. Find out x for `10 ** x` which can multiply your float into an integer.
2. Add one to the enlarged number.
3. Divide your previous multiplier.

So it looks like:

```
n = 0.125
e = len(str(n)) - 2
temp_n = n * 10 ** e
temp_n += 1
n = temp_n / 10 ** e
print n
```

**EDIT:**

In the previous script, things went wrong when the number was very long. Results are truncated by `str()` and `print`, so I changed the script a little:

```
n = 0.1259287345982795
e = len(repr(n)) - 2
temp_n = n * 10 ** e
temp_n += 1
n = temp_n / 10 ** e
print repr(n)
```

Comment: It doesn't work when n is a very small number. `n = 0.125928734598279`, result is `0.125928734599`

Comment: Oh, it's because `str()` and `print` truncates the long string. with the help of `repr()` everything is fine:) I'll update my post.

Comment: You can skip the division by `10**e` and just do `n + 10**-e`

Answer (score 0):

```
n = n + 1/10**(len(repr(n)) - 2)
```

Comment: Even better is `n = n + 10**-(len(repr(n)) - 2)` as suggested by @blender.  See @shengy's first answer for details. I just compacted it and used `repr` to fix it.